# What do the different values of the kind argument mean in scipy.interpolate.interp1d?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

The [SciPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) explains that `interp1d`'s `kind` argument can take the values `‘linear’`, `‘nearest’`, `‘zero’`, `‘slinear’`, `‘quadratic’`, `‘cubic’`. The last three are spline orders and `'linear'` is self-explanatory. What do `'nearest'` and `'zero'` do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `nearest` "snaps" to the nearest data point.
- `zero` is a zero order spline. It's value at any point is the last raw value seen.
- `linear` performs linear interpolation and `slinear` uses a first
  order spline. They use different code and [can produce similar but subtly different results](https://gist.github.com/stringfellow/8ae4d3f25ca525e75bb79c01fbda4a24).
- `quadratic` uses second order spline interpolation.
- `cubic` uses third order spline interpolation.

Note that the `k` parameter can also accept an integer specifying the order of spline interpolation.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

np.random.seed(6)
kinds = ('nearest', 'zero', 'linear', 'slinear', 'quadratic', 'cubic')

N = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.randint(10, size=(N,))

new_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 28)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(kinds)+1, sharex=True)
axs[0].plot(x, y, 'bo-')
axs[0].set_title('raw')
for ax, kind in zip(axs[1:], kinds):
    new_y = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind=kind)(new_x)
    ax.plot(new_x, new_y, 'ro-')
    ax.set_title(kind)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: linear and slinear don't always produce the same result in some pathological cases, see http://gist.github.com/stringfellow/8ae4d3f25ca525e75bb79c01fbda4a24

Comment: @StevePike: That's very interesting, but it looks like that might be an issue specific to Pandas, not scipy. That is to say, when I adapt your data to my code above (without Pandas), `interpolate.interp1d` seems to still produce the same results when `kind='linear'` or `kind='slinear'`.

Comment: aha.. good catch! I assumed pandas is just passing it through... foolish! Quite confusing..

Comment: actually, scipy does differ, see updated test https://gist.github.com/stringfellow/8ae4d3f25ca525e75bb79c01fbda4a24 -- pandas and scipy are the same here - although they look the same on a plot they are different values which is important enough in some cases to not assume they are the same!

Comment: @StevePike: Thanks for carefully tracking this down and for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

‘nearest’ returns data point from X nearest to the argument, or
`interpolates function y=f(x) at the point x using the data point nearest to x`

'zero' I would guess is equivalent to truncation of argument and thus using data point closest toward zero