# Uncertainity about the Interpolate Function in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am working with the interpolate function in `pandas`. Here is a toy example to make an illustrative case:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Data':np.random.normal(size=200), 'Data2':np.random.normal(size=200)}) 

df.iloc[1, 0] = np.nan

print df

print df.interpolate('nearest')
```

My question: Does the `interpolate` function work over multiple columns? That is, does it use multivariate analysis to determine the value for a missing field? Or does it simply look at individual columns?

Comment: individual columns (or rows if axis=1).

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) reference the various available methods - most just rely on the `index`, possibly via the univariate `scipy.interp1d` or other univariate `scipy` methods:

> method : {‘linear’, ‘time’, ‘index’, ‘values’, ‘nearest’, ‘zero’,
>   ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘barycentric’, ‘krogh’, ‘polynomial’,
>   ‘spline’ ‘piecewise_polynomial’, ‘pchip’}

- ‘linear’: ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced. This is the only method supported on MultiIndexes.
- default ‘time’: interpolation works on daily and higher resolution data to interpolate given length of interval ‘index’, ‘values’: use the actual numerical values of the index
- ‘nearest’, ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘barycentric’, ‘polynomial’ is passed to scipy.interpolate.interp1d. Both ‘polynomial’ and ‘spline’ require that you also specify an order (int), e.g. df.interpolate(method=’polynomial’, order=4). These use the actual numerical values of the index.
- ‘krogh’, ‘piecewise_polynomial’, ‘spline’, and ‘pchip’ are all wrappers around the scipy interpolation methods of similar names. These use the actual numerical values of the index.

[Scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#univariate-interpolation) and charts illustrating output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698604/what-do-the-different-values-of-the-kind-argument-mean-in-scipy-interpolate-inte)

Comment: I seen that. But I don't understand whether they are using multivariate imputation or just `interp1d`. I'm hoping that it does this via multivariate analysis.

Comment: If you look at the scipy docs, you'll find that the scipy functions take 1-dim arguments, so they use either the values of a single column or row depending on the given `axis` keyword` (`default=0`, so using individual columns as input).