# Understanding pandas interpolation function

Tags: pandas, scipy, interpolation

I have seen numerous comparisons like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321738/uncertainity-about-the-interpolate-function-in-pandas) but I still don't understand as I don't have issues related to date time and floating point precision.

I am having problem understanding implementation of interpolation function in pandas.

I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'MC':[1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15], 'MW':[1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15]})
df.set_index('MW', inplace=True)
df2 = df.reindex([1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,3,5,11,13,14,16])

df2.apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
      MW
MC      
1    1.0
2    2.0
4    4.0
6    6.0
7    7.0
8    8.0
9    9.0
10  10.0
12  12.0
13  13.0
15  15.0
3   14.5
5   14.0
11  13.5
13  13.0
14  13.0
16  13.0
```

Which looks very unusual result to me for both interpolation and extrapolation. There is no floating point issue playing out here.

When I use scipy interpolation, I get the ***desired result*** but will need to implement separate extrapolation:

```
from scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.interp1d(df.index, df.values.flatten())
f([3,5,11,13,14])
array([  3.,   5.,  11.,  13.,  14.])
```

Edit: I have tried numerous  options as following:

```
df2.interpolate(method='index')
      MW
MC      
1    1.0
2    2.0
4    4.0
6    6.0
7    7.0
8    8.0
9    9.0
10  10.0
12  12.0
13  13.0
15  15.0
3    3.0
5    5.0
11  11.0
13  13.0
14  13.0
16  13.0
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `apply` and passing it `pd.Series.interpolate`? This would be a pretty strange thing to do. Normally, you would just call `df.interpolate()`

Comment: And how did you get your output? I am getting something completely different. What version of pandas do you have? `pd.__version__`. Upgrade if you are not at 0.19

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. From your output it seems like MC is the index. However, you are not setting the index for df or df2. Currently, this code does not produce this output.

Comment: I am using: pd.__version__ u'0.18.1'  in python 2.7. It doesn't upgrade when I try to do pip upgrade. Hence, it might be limitation of 2.7?

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible. Why does df2 have only one column? Why does df2 have MC as the name of the index? MC should still be a column.

Comment: @Ted I had a missing statement of setting index which I fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: It seems pandas is assuming monotonous index. Can you try `df2.sort_index().interpolate(method='index')`?

Comment: It's not that pandas assumes monotonic index but rather `method='linear'` just flat out ignores the index (that's by design).  I believe the behavior above is "correct" for `method='index'` but that extrapolation just fills with nearest (i.e. "ffill") although that isn't in documentation.  It isn't great how pandas works here IMO.  For comparison, stata has a nice approach here for extrapolation in addition to interpolation ("ipolate") but interpolation/extrapolation often requires some extra care whatever package or method you are using.

Comment: @Zanam  I see "desired result" highlighted but am not sure what desired results are.  I don't get  any results from your scipy code (and assume the results you show below that are NOT desired results?)  I suspect you have set this up so that you just want the interpolated/extrapolated results to equal the index?  Which obviously is easy to do but not the best way to set up the example for generality...