# Speeding up iterative process with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a large pandas dataframe `df_gen`containing timeseries data for 10000 customers. The data relates to energy usage. Here's a smaller version of it

```
In[1]: df_gen   
Out[2]: 
                         10053802  10053856  10053898  10058054
2013-01-01 00:00:00     0.196     1.493     0.332     0.278
2013-01-01 00:30:00     0.155     1.497     0.336     0.275
2013-01-01 01:00:00     0.109     1.487       NaN     0.310
2013-01-01 01:30:00     0.703     1.479     0.331     0.272
2013-01-01 02:00:00     0.389     1.533     0.293     0.313
```

I have a process for filling missing data: For a particular customer id, which has missing data at a particular timestamp, find the timestamp that has the most similar data across the dataset and use that to fill the gap.

The reason for using this method is that the energy usage depends on external factors such as external temperature, so, e.g. on hot days, lots of customers have their aircon on. If we find the date and time when most other customers have similar energy use to the date and time of the missing datapoint, that's a good place to fill the missing data from.

It uses a function to identify the timestamp for which the data best matches the timestamp with missing data, by calculating the variance for each row:

```
def best_ts(df,ts_null,null_row):
# finds the timestamp for which the load is closest to the missing load at ts_null across the dataset df
# null_row is the row with the null data to be filled
var_df = pd.Series(index=df.index)
var_df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
if pd.isnull(null_row).all():
        logging.info('No customer data at all for %s ',str(ts_null))
var_df = ((df-null_row).fillna(value=0)**2).sum(axis=1)
smallest = var_df.idxmin()
return smallest
```

The script then iterates for each customer and for each timestamp and when it finds null data, it calls `best_ts` and fills from that timestamp:

```
for id in df_gen.columns:
    for ts in df_gen.index:
        if pd.isnull(df_gen.loc[ts,id]):
        # slice df to remove rows that have no filling data for this customer and use this to fill from
        fill_ts = best_ts(df_gen[df_gen[id].notnull()],ts, df_gen.loc[ts])
        df_gen.loc[ts].fillna(df_gen.loc[fill_ts], inplace=True)
```

**Worked Example**
Using the sample df above, when the `NaN` data is found, `best_ts` is passed 3 parameters: the df with the missing-data row removed, the timestamp with missing data, and the row of missing data as a pandas Series

```
In: df_gen[df_gen[id].notnull()]
Out: 
                     10053802  10053856  10053898  10058054
2013-01-01 00:00:00     0.196     1.493     0.332     0.278
2013-01-01 00:30:00     0.155     1.497     0.336     0.275
2013-01-01 01:30:00     0.703     1.479     0.331     0.272
2013-01-01 02:00:00     0.389     1.533     0.293     0.313

In: ts
Out: 

datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 0)

In: df_gen.loc[ts]
Out: 
10053802    0.109
10053856    1.487
10053898      NaN
10058054    0.310
```

Within the function, a pandas series `var_df` is created with the same DateTimeIndex as the dataframe. Each value is variance, i.e. the sum of squares difference between the energy values for each customer and the energy values for timestamp `ts`.

e.g the first value in `var_df` is given by ((0.196-0.109)^2 + (1.493-1.487)^2 + 0 + (0.278-0.310)^2) = 0.008629

```
In: var_df
Out: 
2013-01-01 00:00:00    0.008629
2013-01-01 00:30:00    0.003441
2013-01-01 01:30:00    0.354344
2013-01-01 02:00:00    0.080525
dtype: float64
```

So timestamp `2013-01-01 00:30:00` is the time most 'like' the time of the missing data, so this is chosen to fill the missing data from.

So the filled dataframe looks like this:

```
In: df_gen
Out: 
                     10053802  10053856  10053898  10058054
2013-01-01 00:00:00     0.196     1.493     0.332     0.278
2013-01-01 00:30:00     0.155     1.497     0.336     0.275
2013-01-01 01:00:00     0.109     1.487     0.336     0.310
2013-01-01 01:30:00     0.703     1.479     0.331     0.272
2013-01-01 02:00:00     0.389     1.533     0.293     0.313
```

(Note: In this small example, the 'best' timestamp happens to be the one immediately preceeding the missing data, but in the full dataset it could be any one of the 17519 timestamps in the year.)

This code works but man is it slow! It's going to take about 2 months to get through the dataset! I would love suggestions to speed it up, either by avoiding the nested iteration or by speeding up the function.

Comment: Does the processing order matter? i.e. do we need to do customer `10006414` before customer `10006572`? If not you could look at using multiprocessing, otherwise using ctypes might speed up your loops.

Comment: Have you considered using [`pandas.Dataframe.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) instead of rolling your own interpolation algorithm? It seems you are attempting to do what `"nearest"` does, but I'm sure it does it *much more efficiently*.

Comment: @jprockbelly - No, order is not important. Don't know anything about  multiprocessing but PC has 16 cores, so definitely worth finding out about.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have had a look at that documentation. I don't think "nearest" does what i am trying to do, though I don't fully understand the different methods given there.

Comment: @doctorer check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27698894/5014455)

Comment: And might as well look at the `pandas` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#interpolation).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - .interpolate is not what I need as I am not filling from nearby timestamps. I'm looking right across the dataset (ie for all other customers) and finding the timestamp that has the most similar data, and using that to fill from. A completely different process.

Comment: You don't provide sufficient data to demonstrate the problem.  Nor do you provide an example calculation.  Its generally not a good idea to expect that your code documents your thoughts.  Please spend the time to walk us through a calculation.  And show us what filling in a missing looks like.

Comment: @doctorer yea, I agree, you need to walk us through your reasoning. And more importantly, why is this the way you want to do it vs all the methods provided...

Comment: @piRSquared juanpa.arrivillaga  I have editted the question to show a worked example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your similarity metric is computing the sum of element-wise squared distances between each column.  One approach, admittedly a bit clunky (but making use of fast Pandas operations), is to:

1. Iterate over each column, and create a new data frame with the same dimensions as the original, but where every column is a copy of the current column.
2. Use `df.subtract().pow(2).sum()` to compute similarity, and, ignoring the column that subtracted itself, find the column name (i.e. customer id) of the minimum value.
3. Update the missing value in the current column with the corresponding value in the matched column.

What follows is a rough draft, but it may be enough to adapt to your use case.  One big assumption with this implementation is that there can be only one missing data point per customer. The code should be generalizable to multiple missing data points per customer, with a little work. Accordingly, when testing this code, make sure the randomly-generated `df` has only one missing data point per column.  (It usually does, but not always.)

**Generate sample data**

```
dates = pd.date_range('20170101', periods=10, freq='D')
ids = [10006414, 10006572, 10006630, 10006664, 10006674]
values = np.random.random(size=len(dates)*len(ids)).reshape(10,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=dates, columns=ids)

# insert random missing data
nan_size = 4
for _ in range(nan_size):
    nan_row = np.random.randint(0, df.shape[0])
    nan_col = np.random.randint(0, df.shape[1])
    df.iloc[nan_row, nan_col] = np.nan
```

**Perform matching interpolation**

```
def get_closest(customer, dims):
    cust = customer.name
    nrow = dims[0]
    ncol = dims[1]
    replace_row = df.index[df[cust].isnull()]
    # make data frame full of cust data
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.loc[:,cust], ncol).values.reshape(nrow,ncol), 
                       index=dates, columns=ids)
    replace_col = (df.subtract(df2)
                     .pow(2)
                     .sum()
                     .replace({0:np.nan}) # otherwise 0 will go to top of sort
                     .sort_values()
                     .index[0] # index here is matching customer id
                  )
    customer[replace_row] = df.ix[replace_row, replace_col]
    return customer

print(df.apply(get_closest, axis='rows', args=(df.shape,)))
```

**UPDATE**
Based on OP's clarification, the goal is to make row-wise comparisons (i.e. finding the most similar timestamp) instead of column-wise comparisons (i.e. finding the most similar customer).  Below is an updated version of `get_closest()`, which makes row-wise comparisons, and which handles multiple missing values smoothly.

I also added a reporting function, which will print each timestamp that contains missing entries across all customers, along with the timestamp that was used to impute missing values.  Reporting is turned off by default, just pass in `True` as a second `args` entry in `apply()` to turn it on.

**UPDATE 2**
The updated row-wise `get_closest()` now accounts for edge cases where the nearest timestamp also has `NaN` values for the customer column that needs imputation.  Now, the function will search for the nearest timestamp that *also* has available data for the missing values that need to be imputed.

Sample data:

```
            10006414  10006572  10006630  10006664  10006674
2017-01-01  0.374593  0.982585  0.059732  0.513149  0.251808
2017-01-02  0.269229  0.998531  0.523589  0.780806  0.033106
2017-01-03  0.261173  0.828637  0.638376  0.314944  0.737646
2017-01-04  0.786112  0.101750  0.286983  0.242778  0.341717
2017-01-05  0.230358  0.387392  0.918353  0.206100       NaN
2017-01-06  0.715966  0.206121  0.153461  0.894511  0.765227
2017-01-07  0.095002  0.169697  0.465624  0.109404  0.212315
2017-01-08  0.474712       NaN  0.471861  0.773374  0.454295
2017-01-09       NaN  0.201928  0.228018  0.173968  0.248485
2017-01-10  0.542635       NaN  0.132974  0.692073  0.201721
```

**ROW-WISE `get_closest()`**

```
def get_closest(row, dims, report=False):
    if row.isnull().sum():
        ts_with_nan = row.name
        nrow, ncol = dims
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df.loc[ts_with_nan], nrow).reshape(nrow,ncol), 
                           index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
        most_similar_ts = (df.subtract(df2, axis='rows', fill_value=0)
                             .pow(2)
                             .sum(axis=1, skipna=True)
                             .sort_values()
                          )
        # remove current row from matched indices
        most_similar_ts = most_similar_ts[most_similar_ts.index != ts_with_nan] 
        # narrow down to only columns where replacements would occur
        match_vals = df.ix[most_similar_ts.index, df.loc[ts_with_nan].isnull()]
        # select only rows where all values are non-empty
        all_valid = match_vals.notnull().all(axis=1)
        # take the timestamp index of the first row of match_vals[all_valid]
        best_match = match_vals[all_valid].head(1).index[0]
        if report:
            print('MISSING VALUES found at timestamp: {}'.format(ts_with_nan.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
            print('            REPLACEMENT timestamp: {}'.format(best_match.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

        # replace missing values with matched data
        return row.fillna(df.loc[best_match])

    return row

df.apply(get_closest, axis='columns', args=(df.shape, True)) # report=True
```

Output:

```
# MISSING VALUES found at timestamp: 2017-01-02 00:00:00
            # REPLACEMENT timestamp: 2017-01-09 00:00:00
# MISSING VALUES found at timestamp: 2017-01-07 00:00:00
            # REPLACEMENT timestamp: 2017-01-10 00:00:00
# MISSING VALUES found at timestamp: 2017-01-09 00:00:00
            # REPLACEMENT timestamp: 2017-01-03 00:00:00

print(df)
            10006414  10006572  10006630  10006664  10006674
2017-01-01  0.374593  0.982585  0.059732  0.513149  0.251808
2017-01-02  0.269229  0.998531  0.523589  0.780806  0.033106
2017-01-03  0.261173  0.828637  0.638376  0.314944  0.737646
2017-01-04  0.786112  0.101750  0.286983  0.242778  0.341717
2017-01-05  0.230358  0.387392  0.918353  0.206100  0.212315
2017-01-06  0.715966  0.206121  0.153461  0.894511  0.765227
2017-01-07  0.095002  0.169697  0.465624  0.109404  0.212315
2017-01-08  0.474712  0.201928  0.471861  0.773374  0.454295
2017-01-09  0.095002  0.201928  0.228018  0.173968  0.248485
2017-01-10  0.542635  0.201928  0.132974  0.692073  0.201721
```

In addition to this row-wise approach, I've kept the original version of `get_closest()` at the start of this answer, as I can see value in imputation based on "nearest customer", rather than "nearest timestamp", and it may be useful as a point of reference for others in the future.

**UPDATE 3**
OP provided this updated and finalized solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe of random data
dates = pd.date_range('20170101', periods=10, freq='D')
ids = [10006414, 10006572, 10006630, 10006664, 10006674]
values = np.random.random(size=len(dates)*len(ids)).reshape(10,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=dates, columns=ids)

# insert random missing data
nan_size = 20
for _ in range(nan_size):
    nan_row = np.random.randint(0, df.shape[0])
    nan_col = np.random.randint(0, df.shape[1])
    df.iloc[nan_row, nan_col] = np.nan

print ('Original df is ', df)
def get_closest(row, dims, report=False):
    if row.isnull().sum():
        ts_with_nan = row.name
        nrow, ncol = dims
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df.loc[ts_with_nan], nrow).reshape(nrow, ncol), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
        most_similar_ts = (df.subtract(df2, axis='rows')
                           .pow(2)
                           .sum(axis=1, skipna=True)
                           .sort_values())
        # remove current row from matched indices
        most_similar_ts = most_similar_ts[most_similar_ts.index != ts_with_nan]
        if report:
            print('MISSING VALUES found at timestamp: {}'.format(ts_with_nan.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
        while row.isnull().sum():
            # narrow down to only columns where replacements would occur
            match_vals = df.ix[most_similar_ts.index, df.loc[ts_with_nan].isnull()]
            # fill from closest ts
            best_match = match_vals.head(1).index[0]
            row = row.fillna(df.loc[best_match])

            if report:
                print('            REPLACEMENT timestamp: {}'.format(best_match.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
            # Any customers with remaining NaNs in df.loc[ts_with_nan] also have NaNs in df.loc[best_match]
            # so remove this ts from the results and repeat the process
            most_similar_ts = most_similar_ts[most_similar_ts.index != best_match]
        return row


    return row

df_new = df.apply(get_closest, axis='columns', args=(df.shape, True))  # report=True
print ('Final df is ', df_new)
```

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece This is very helpful but not quite what i'm after - I'm updating from the same column (customer ID) using a different row (timestamp) so need to swap the dimensions. It also needs to work for multiple Nulls for each customer and for each timestamp, which may require iteration, but only through a subset of teh data.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.  Looking at your example case, you want to fine the timestamp (row) with the smallest sum of squares (call this `row_SSE`) in relation to another row that contains missing value(s) (call this row `row_missing`).  Then replace each `NaN` in `row_missing` with the value in `row_SSE` that's in the same column as the `NaN`.  This could happen 0 or more times per timestamp.  And this approach does not solve the problem of a customer having missing data in both `row_missing` and `row_SEE`, but you're willing to accept those edge cases for now.  Is that all correct?

Comment: Thank you. Your description of the problem is correct, except that I will need to deal with those edge cases. That is why I originally iterated for customers and then for timestamps, to allow different `row_SSE` for each customer. But probably better to accept those edge cases and then do a second sweep to pick them up by iterating through customers who still have missing data and calling `get_closest()` for each, but using a `df` with that customer removed.

Comment: ...but this isn't working correctly. 
`In: df2` 
`Out:
            10006414  10006572  10006630  10006664  10006674
2017-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2017-01-02       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2017-01-03  0.296268  0.296268  0.296268  0.296268  0.296268
2017-01-04  0.296268  0.296268  0.296268  0.296268  0.296268
2017-01-05  0.184410  0.184410  0.184410  0.184410  0.184410
2017-01-06  0.184410  0.184410  0.184410  0.184410  0.184410
2017-01-07  0.144101  0.144101  0.144101  0.144101  0.144101
....`

Comment: This line `df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.loc[ts_with_nan], nrow).values.reshape(nrow, ncol), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)`
isn't working for me (in py 3.6)

Comment: I have an update that solves your edge case problem.  But before I post, can you describe more specifically what isn't working correctly in the two comments you just posted?  If there's an error message, please copy in its entirety.  If it's a problem with the data output, please describe the problem clearly.

Comment: See updated solution.  That should be enough to sufficiently answer the question posed here - if you have more questions, I'm happy to help "offline", just send me a message.

Comment: Thanks again @andrew_reece No error message but my understanding of your method is that `df2' should consist of multiple rows of `missing_row` but when I interrupt the script (using PyCharm debugger) it does not (see my earlier comment), so the calculation based on this will be incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142433/discussion-between-andrew-reece-and-doctorer).

Comment: Using `np.tile' instead of `np.repeat` to populate `df2` has solved this issue.

Comment: I found a bug in here. When doing the subtraction `fill_value=0` distorts the sum of squares calculation by including values for 'difference from NaN' I have edited to remove this. Also added alternative treatment of edge cases. (Edits are subject to peer review)

Comment: I made an edit to fix a bug in this answer but it has been rejected. I'm not sure why people prefer the buggy version?

Comment: I made another edit which altered the method slightly to fit the original question. Again this was rejected. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it took all weekend to get back to you but here is an example of how to convert this to a threaded process.

First off you need to turn your loop into a function that accepts 2 arguments. Here is my version, note that it now accepts a tuple of `id_` and `ts`, (I have avoided using `id` as it is an existing python function)

```
def my_func(item): #takes a tuple of id and ts 
    id_, ts = item
    if pd.isnull(df_gen.loc[ts,id_]):
        # slice df to remove rows that have no filling data for this customer and use this to fill from
        fill_ts = best_ts(df_gen[df_gen[id_].notnull()],ts, df_gen.loc[ts])
        df_gen.loc[ts].fillna(df_gen.loc[fill_ts], inplace=True)
```

We also need to set up some process that feeds this function all the combinations of `id_` and `ts` that we want to check. We can make use of the very handy `itertools` library to make this easy:

```
from itertools import product
product(df_gen.columns, df_gen.index)
```

(Even if you don't want to using threading you can still use this to reduce your nested for loop)

Now we have our function and our inputs we can parallelise it! The [bottom of the docs for](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html) `queue` gives a great example of how to set this up. So borrowing from that example:

```
import threading
from itertools import product
from queue import Queue

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get() #get the next item in the queue
        if item is None:
            break
        my_func(item) #send item to your function here
        q.task_done() #remove from queue once done

q = Queue() #create a queue object
threads = []
num_worker_threads = 8 #pick a number that works for you, I suggest trying a few between 4 and 200

#create a list of threads
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

#create a queue of items
#this example is ok for a relativley small dataframe
#for your actual big dataframe you way want to do this in chucks
for item in product(df_gen.columns, df_gen.index): 
    q.put(item) #put items in my queue

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()
```

I suggests starting with a subset of your data and testing a few different worker numbers. Lots is not always better, it depends on the code being run and hardware being use to run it.